# VB6 - Populate User Defined Type Array from Stored Procedure then Find Item in Array

Tags: arrays, vb6, user-defined-types

I am coming from more of a .NET background and need to make some changes to a very old VB6 application.

The .NET equivalent of what I'm trying to do now in VB6 is, define a (model) class with 3 properties

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string Ref { get; set; }
  public string OldNumber { get; set; }
  public string NewNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In .NET I would then call a stored procedure to return a set of results (there could be a few thousand records) and assign them to, for example, an instance of `List<MyClass>`.

I could then, whenever I need to, attempt to find an item within this List, where the 'Ref' property is 'blah', and use this item/its other properties (OldNumber and NewNumber).

However, in VB6, I don't know how this same process is best achieved. Can anyone please help?

Comment: If you want to cache results in RAM like that why not just query for them into a static client-side Recordset then disconnect it?  You can do .Find on that to locate rows.  Or is this program so old and moldy that it is using DAO?

Comment: Under project menu of VB6 IDE, select "Add Class Module". A new class module gets added to the project. In this you can declare the members like Ref, OldNumber, NewNumber etc, and have LET and GET methods defined. And then we can declare an array of this class object as you require in your case.

Comment: @Bob77 If you post this as an answer I will accept it as I hadn't thought about this approach and it's doing the job nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ADO you can cache results by querying into a static cursor client-side Recordset and then disconnecting it.

You can use Sort, Find, Filter, etc. and move through the rows as needed.  You can even improve searches by building a local index within the Recordset after opening and disconnecting it by using the Field object's `Optimize` dynamic property.  See:

[Optimize Property-Dynamic (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the additional information on the Optimize dynamic property. Perfect.